# Check box values storing in different columns of database using php (In a loop)

Tags: php, html, css

Check box values storing in different columns of database using php (In a loop).
Can any one help me with an example please.

Comment: please show your code, what you have tried till now

Comment: Please share your code first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147738/store-checkbox-value-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy without any code. But it's the same like the storage of other datas (text, select, ...)

```
Insert into XXX $_POST['data'] WHERE condition;

Insert into YYY $_POST['data'] WHERE condition;
```

Comment: can u give me your mail id??